# Pagination, how to create a limited range of numbers to paginate through

Tags: php, algorithm, pagination

I'm building a simple Pagination Class that just expects the number of items to paginate through and a desired limit (items per page).

After all calculations i also build an array with just the numbers for the pages that can be paginated through, so when i need to build the links in HTML, i just "print" the numbers returned from the Class.

Currently it works so far, but it's more or less "hard coded" to exact 5 numbers. Any ideas, how i could make the following method returns a variable amount of numbers?

```php
/**
 * Builds a list with 5 numbers
 * 
 * @param int current page
 * @param int pages total
 * @return array
 */
function navNumbered(int $page, int $pages): array
{
    // $r = [START, END];
    // if $pages are less than 5, just return from 1 to X
    if ($pages <= 5) {
        $r = [1, $pages];
    } elseif ($page-2 > 0) {
        // prevents from getting under 0 
        $r = [$page-2, $page+2];
        // prevents from getting over the number of $pages total
        if ($r[1] > $pages)
            $r = [$pages-4, $pages];
    } elseif ($page-1 > 0) {
        // prevents from getting under 0
        $r = [$page-1, $page+3];
    } else $r = [$page, $page+4];
    return range($r[0], $r[1]);
}

print_r(navNumbered(8, 9));

// if page is any between 1 to 3 from 9, returns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// if page is 6 from 9, returns: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
// or if page is any between 7 to 9 from 9, returns: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I would like to give a number as third parameter to set how many numbers should be returned, but since i try, my brain hurts whenever i just think of this. Any ideas?

---

---

To close this thread. I've found a solution based on predefined steps. It's not the solution i would've like to find, but at least one, with that i can live so far.

I guess it could be made more flexible with some calculations, but that would be only end in lot of calculations that i want to avoid in first place, so.

```php
/**
 * Builds a list with X numbers
 * 
 * @param int current page
 * @param int pages total
 * @param int total amount of visible numbers
 * @return array
 */
function varNav(int $page, int $pages, int $total=5): array
{
    if ($pages <= $total)
        return \range(1, $pages >= 1 ? $pages : 1);

    // predefined steps
    switch($total) {
        default:
        case 3: $s = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]; break;
        case 4: $s = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]; break;
        case 5: $s = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4]; break;
        case 6: $s = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]; break;
    }

    // make sure $page is never below 1
    $page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;

    // build numbers
    if ($page-$s[0] > 0) {
        $r = [$page-$s[0], $page+$s[2]];
        if ($r[1] > $pages)
            $r = [$pages-$s[4], $pages];
    } elseif ($page-$s[1] > 0)
        $r = [$page-$s[1], $page+$s[3]];
    else $r = [$page, $page+$s[4]];

    return \range($r[0], $r[1]);
}
```

For quick testings

```php
// out
$buildNav = function($pages, $show, $increment) {
    $cPage = $_GET["page_$increment"] ?? 1;
    $nav = varNav($cPage+0, $pages, $show);
    foreach($nav as $page)
        \printf(' <a href="?%s" style="display:inline-block;padding:1.5rem">%s %s</a> '
            , \http_build_query(\array_merge($_GET, ["page_$increment" => $page]))
            , $page
            , $page == $cPage ? 'active' : null
        );
    return \printf('<p>%s | pages: <b>%s</b></p><hr />', \implode(', ', $nav), $pages);
};

print '<p><a href="?">reset</a></p>';
$buildNav(17, 6, 1);
$buildNav(43, 5, 2);
$buildNav(27, 4, 3);
$buildNav(4, 3, 4);
$buildNav(2, 3, 5);
$buildNav(1, 3, 6);
```